# SQL statements without group by

Tags: sql

If I wanted to find all values in a table that occur more than twice without using group by, how would I do that? I understand how to do this with group by and was curious how to do it without group by **(EDIT: could you do this with join?)**.

For example, if I had last names in a certain zip code, and I wanted to find entries with this last name more than twice, how would I do this without group by in SQL statements?

I tried

```
select name, count() from population order by name asc having count() > 2;
```

but that doesn't do what I want it to. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you not want to use `group by`?

Comment: What did GROUP BY ever do to you?   He's a perfectly nice clause... cleans up after himself, good with kids... what gives?

Comment: Have you thought about using group by but joining it to the ungrouped data?

Answer (score 2):

Being this tagged only as `sql` it seems a general solution is being looked for. Since the [SQL:2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2003) revision it should be fair to say that this can be solved with window functions:

```
SELECT name FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name) rank,
    name
  FROM population
) s
WHERE rank = 3
```

See a sample fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/79356/1).

Anyway, the fact that it is possible to solve this without a `GROUP BY` doesn't mean that it should :)

Comment: Or `WHERE rank = 3` and you don't need the `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [correlated query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) can work for you. Please check.

Assuming the data set given below

```
Id  Zip     Lastname
--- -----   --------
101 12345   John
102 12345   John
103 12345   John
104 12345   Ram
105 12345   Kelly
106 12345   Kelly
107 45678   Krishna
108 45678   Krishna
109 45678   Krishna
110 45678   David
111 45678   David
```

Query

```
select * from test.population pop1 
where 2 < (select count(*) from test.population pop2 
       where pop1.Lastname=pop2.Lastname and pop1.Zipcode = pop2.Zipcode)
```

The output of above query is

```
Id  Zip     Lastname
--- ------  --------
101 12345   John
102 12345   John
103 12345   John
107 45678   Krishna
108 45678   Krishna
109 45678   Krishna
```